# A Bijective quasiisometry between finitely generated groups is a biLipschitz equivalence

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I want to show that any bijective quasiisometry $f:G\to H$ (whith $G$ and $H$ groups, finitely genered by S and T respectely) is a biLipshitz equivalence.

I know this:

There are constants $\lambda\geq 1$ and $C\geq 0$ such that $f$ is a $(\lambda, C)-$quasiisometry, ie: for any $a,b\in G$: $$\frac
{1}{\lambda }d_S(a,b)-C\leq d_T(f(a), f(b))\leq \lambda d_S(a,b)+C$$

My idea: clearly this is true for any $\lambda^\prime\geq \lambda$ and $C^\prime \geq C$, I suposse that i can take $\lambda^\prime$   big enough such that $f$ is a $(\lambda^\prime,0)-$quasiisometry, then $f$ a surjective biLipshitz  and thus $f$ is a biLipshitz equivalence.

But I don't know how to prove it.

Your suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  :)

Comment: hint: treat separately $d_S(a,b)\ge 2C\lambda$ and $d_S(a,b)\le 2C\lambda$.

Comment: Any suggestion to see this? I think that if $d_S(a,b)\leq 2C\lambda$, then $d_T(f(a), f(b))\leq 2C\lambda+C$ and then $H$ has finite diameter and this might not be so